# Image is not auto adjusting

Tags: android, android-imageview

In android, when we open a screenshot from gallery. It comes blurred for 2 secs and then auto adjusts itself.

But when I am using this screenshot image to set on a imageview using image path as :,

Image Path is: /mnt/sdcard/ScreenCapture/SC20130219-124221.png

```
private void showImage(String imgPath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Image Path is:  "+imgPath);

        ImageView openImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_fullScreen);
        ExifInterface exifMedia = null;
        try {
            exifMedia = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String exifOrint = exifMedia.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        int exifOrientation = Integer.parseInt(exifOrint);
        System.out.println("Orientation Tag is:"+exifOrientation);
        BitmapFactory.Options mOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        mOptions.inSampleSize=2;
        Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,mOptions);
        //Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        imgBitmap = getResizedBitmapImage(imgBitmap, 200, 200, exifOrientation);
        openImage.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
    }
```

Another case: While getting the Bitmap from the URL as :

```
URL url = new URL(urlTarget);
            BitmapFactory.Options mOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            mOptions.inSampleSize=1;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                    .openConnection().getInputStream(),null,mOptions);
```

Then the image is not auto adjusted itself. It comes BLURRED. THIS IS MY PROBLEM.

IT IS IN THE CASE OF SCREENSHOT ONLY.

tHANKS

Comment: Could you paste getResizedBitmapImage() method?

Comment: It is a screenshot so use `mOptions.inSampleSize=1;`. Otherwise, it will definitely become blurred

Comment: Hello @SherifelKhatib It has helped me in the above case but in the case of getting the bitmap from the URL, it is not working. Can you please tell me how to use inSampleSize in case of getting the bitmap from the URL. I have edited my code. Please have a look

Comment: Maybe the image you're decoding from the url is too small (thats why it is getting blurred). Try to use scaleType="center" in your ImageView with id `img_fullScreen`

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what you are asking. Can you discuss more of the problem before posting your code?

Comment: did you used buffer_size in your code,if used then increase  buffer_size.and one more increase buffer_size while saving Screen shot also

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Hi sherif your answer has helped me.. Please answer it below and I will give you   50 points

Comment: It is okay. you accepted my answer by Akhilesh

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Okay, Thanks bro. In future please give answer instead of simply commenting. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

`mOptions.inSampleSize=2;` This is going to skip alternate pixel data and load an image 1/2 the original size. *Of-course* it will look blurred and highly aliased, because this is no where near a good [image scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) algorithm.

As far as Gallery app is concerned, it loads progressively, it shows a thumbnail, or a quick render, while full resolution image is being loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tricky behavior of the Android Gallery app (and also is a good example show how to make better user experience if you have to load large images). 
At first, when you click on the image thumbnail in the gallery, it will use exactly that thumbnail to display in the ImageView. Because the thumbnail is small and it needs to be scale up to fix the ImageView, you will see it blur.
While displaying the thumbnail to user, it also decoding the original image. When everything's done, the original image will be displayed instead of the thumbnail. 
The Gallery also use the animation when switching between the thumbnail and original image (default layout animation you can find it in API Demos)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from `mOptions.inSampleSize = 2` to `mOptions.inSampleSize =1`
And your problem will definitely be resolved